# guix pull throws "match-error"

Tags: debian, guix

i have installed package [guix](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/guix) (on debian bullseye).

and try to run `guix pull` as it is written in the [documentation](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Upgrading-Guix.html#Upgrading-Guix):

```
$ sudo -i guix pull
Updating channel 'guix' from Git repository at 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/guix.git'...
Building from this channel:
  guix      https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/guix.git   b329c21
Backtrace:
           6 (apply-smob/1 #<catch-closure 7faa14873220>)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
    705:2  5 (call-with-prompt _ _ #<procedure default-prompt-handle…>)
In ice-9/eval.scm:
    619:8  4 (_ #(#(#<directory (guile-user) 7faa144f0140>)))
In guix/ui.scm:
  2117:12  3 (run-guix-command _ . _)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
    829:9  2 (catch _ _ #<procedure 7faa1446a280 at guix/ui.scm:702…> …)
    829:9  1 (catch _ _ #<procedure 7faa1446a298 at guix/ui.scm:842…> …)
    829:9  0 (catch _ _ #<procedure 7faa119b30a8 at guix/scripts/pu…> …)

ice-9/boot-9.scm:829:9: In procedure catch:
Throw to key `match-error' with args `("match" "no matching pattern" (
#:re-export-and-replace (delete) 
#:replace ((define-public* . define-public)) 
#:export (content-hash content-hash? content-hash-algorithm content-hash-value 
origin origin? this-origin origin-uri origin-method origin-hash origin-sha256 
origin-file-name origin-actual-file-name origin-patches origin-patch-flags 
origin-patch-inputs origin-patch-guile origin-snippet origin-modules 
base32 base64 package package? this-package package-name package-upstream-name 
package-version package-full-name package-source package-build-system 
package-arguments package-inputs package-native-inputs package-propagated-inputs 
package-outputs package-native-search-paths package-search-paths package-replacement 
package-synopsis package-description package-license package-home-page 
package-supported-systems package-properties package-location 
package-definition-location hidden-package hidden-package? package-superseded 
deprecated-package package-field-location this-package-input this-package-native-input 
lookup-package-input lookup-package-native-input lookup-package-propagated-input 
lookup-package-direct-input prepend replace modify-inputs package-direct-sources 
package-transitive-sources package-direct-inputs package-transitive-inputs 
package-transitive-target-inputs package-transitive-native-inputs 
package-transitive-propagated-inputs package-transitive-native-search-paths 
package-transitive-supported-systems package-mapping package-input-rewriting 
package-input-rewriting/spec package-source-derivation package-derivation 
package-cross-derivation package-output package-grafts package-patched-vulnerabilities 
package-with-patches package-with-extra-patches package-with-c-toolchain 
package/inherit transitive-input-references %supported-systems %hurd-systems 
%cuirass-supported-systems supported-package? &package-error package-error? 
package-error-package &package-input-error package-input-error? 
package-error-invalid-input &package-cross-build-system-error 
package-cross-build-system-error? package->bag bag->derivation bag-direct-inputs 
bag-transitive-inputs bag-transitive-host-inputs bag-transitive-build-inputs 
bag-transitive-target-inputs package-development-inputs package-closure 
default-guile default-guile-derivation set-guile-for-build package-file 
package->derivation package->cross-derivation origin->derivation)))'.
```

(i added newlines for better readability).

how to fix this error?

Comment: `$ guix pull --branch=version-1.3.0` — this helped to get rid of the error. but how do i upgrade to master now? `guix pull: error: aborting update of channel 'guix' to commit 1ca2c6730b58c2779fa6837728e90273ad9c042d, which is not a descendant of aa34d4d28dfe25ba47d5800d05000fb7221788c0` and `$ guix pull --allow-downgrades` throws the same 'match-error'

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1001833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Vagrant Cascadian suggested](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1001833#10), intermediate steps should be taken.

1. update guix to the commit tagged as [`v1.3.0`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/tag/?h=v1.3.0) (hash `a0178d3...`):

   ```
   $ guix pull --commit=a0178d3
   ...
   ```
2. then use this version of the script to pull master branch:

   ```
   $ ~/.config/guix/current/bin/guix pull
   ```
3. and install any package (`guile` for example):

   ```
   $ ~/.config/guix/current/bin/guix install guile
   ```

   to initialize your main profile (`~/.guix-profile`).

   now you have:

   1. `~/.config/guix/current/bin/guix` — the newest version of `guix` script.
   2. `~/.guix-profile` — your main profile.
4. to put it all together and start using guix, you need to re-login. this will sourced `/etc/profile.d/guix.sh` that adds to `$PATH` two dirs: `${HOME}/.guix-profile/bin` and `${HOME}/.config/guix/current/bin`.